# Did Tertullian deny baptismal regeneration?

Tags: baptism, tertullian

I often hear that Tertullian was the earliest denier of baptismal regeneration among the post-apostolic church fathers. However, I see quotes like these which say the opposite:

> “A treatise on our sacrament of water, by which the sins of our earlier blindness are washed away and we are released for eternal life will not be superfluous…. Taking away death by the washing away of sins. The guilt being removed, the penalty, of course, is also removed…. Baptism itself is a corporal act by which we are plunged into the water, while its effect is spiritual, in that we are freed from our sins” (On Baptism 1:1, 5:6, 7:2 [inter A.D. 200-206]).

What is the origin or basis for the claim that Tertullian rejected baptismal regeneration, and is it an accurate claim?